# How can i calculate this limit:$\frac{\ln(1+2x^3y^2)}{x^3(1+y)}$ as $(x,y) \to (0,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can i calculate this limit:
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,1)} \frac{\ln\left(1+2x^3 y^2\right)}{x^3(1+y)}?
$$

I've been trying to find this limit with the "sandwich rule" so I found an expression which is bigger than this function: 
$$
\frac{2x^3 y^2}{x^3(1+y)} = \frac{2y^2}{1+y} \to 1
$$
But I'm stuck looking for an expression which is smaller than this function.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Rewrite it as $$\frac{\ln(1+2x^3y^2)}{2x^3y^2}\cdot \frac{2y^2}{1+y}$$

Comment: Thanks, but i still don't see how I can do it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you know $$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+z)}z$$

Comment: Yes, thanks. I understand now.